# Sparse Matrix multiplication in Java

Tags: java, matrix, multiplication, sparse-matrix

Hello I know there are a lot of questions on sparse matrix multiplication, but many of the answers say to just use libraries. I want to do it without using library functions. So far I've done the easy part, getting my matrices into the form of
element array
column array
row    array.

What I need help with is the logic portion. If matrix A is M*N and matrix B is N*P, how do I do this? I considered iterating over the elements in matrix A and checking if it's rowA== colB, and if so if colA==rowB and if that's true then multiply. I currently know my version is wrong, but I can't think of a way to make it right.

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    sum = 0;    
    for(int k = 0; k < cols; k++)
        if (row_values.get(i) == col_valuesb.get(k))
            if (col_values.get(i) == row_valuesb.get(k))
            {
                sum += (short) (elements.get(i)*elementsb.get(k));
            }
    elementsc.add(sum);
    row_valuesc.add(row_values.get(i));
    col_valuesc.add(col_values.get(k));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> "I considered iterating over the elements in matrix A and checking if it's rowA== colB, >and if so if colA==rowB"

Well, since two matrices are, by definition, able to multiply if and only if colA==rowB, then shouldn't you modify

```
if (row_values.get(i) == col_valuesb.get(k)){
            if (col_values.get(i) == row_valuesb.get(k))
            {
```

and just make it

```
if (row_values.get(i) == col_valuesb.get(k)){
```

instead?